# pandas seris last I want to get data for last 3 days or 3 years or 3 months or 3 seconds from today?

Tags: python, pandas

my data

```
data=[{'content': '2018', 'time': 1528186319, 'title': '2018-06-05 16:11:59', 'info': '', 'id': 1}, {'content': '2019', 'time': 1559722345, 'title': '2019-06-05 16:12:25, 'info': '', 'id': 2}, {'content': '017', 'time': 1496650502, 'title': '2017-06-05 16:15:02, 'info': '', 'id': 4}, {'content': '160', 'time': 1465114543, 'title': '2016-06-05 16:15:43', 'info': '', 'id': 5}]
```

my code

```
s = pd.Series(data)
s.index =pd.to_datetime([i['time'] for i in self.dt], utc=True, unit='s').tz_convert('Asia/Shanghai')
sort = s.sort_index()
print(list(sort.last('3d')))
```

but i get error data

```
{'content': '2019', 'time': 1559722345, 'title': '2019-06-05 16:12:25', 'info': '', 'id': 2}
```

I need last 3 days or 3 years or 3 months or 3 seconds from today:
but get 2019-06-05 data

i hope data is []

Comment: last if has not data,must return the last piece of data

Comment: return last 3 days data

Comment: current year 2020

Comment: yes, but pandas get 2019-06-05

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215359/discussion-between-xin-chen-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 0):

One idea if need last 3 days from today first filter rows by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with today timestamp converted to days (removed times by set to `00:00:00`) and then use [`Series.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.last.html):

```
today = pd.Timestamp('now').floor('d')

print(list(sort[sort.index <= today].last('3d')))
```

Comment: i hope data is []

Comment: 2019-06-08  in 2019
not in 2020

Comment: thank, Can not be improved according to last()? because i need last 3D, last 3Y,last3Y

Comment: @xin.chen - understand, first filter values to today and then use `last`, answer was edited.